# Magento adding too many zeros to quantity

Tags: php, magento, product, stock

So I am working on a site that uses magento and I noticed when I go to a product the quantity in stock displays the correct value, but with too many zeros on the end of it like this :
[image]

I found the code where this may be changed:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve this you need to find from which file this is comming

for that use Template Path Hint extension in Magento

then after then the code like :

```
number_format('QTY-VARIABLE',2);
```

so it will add 2 zero only and if you not want to add then in second param put `0`

let me know you want to know more

Comment: I added a picture of the code that is associated with it, where in there would I put that line of code?

Comment: change this $v->getCustomoptionsQty() to number_format($v->getCustomoptionsQty(),2) before the in stock text only

Comment: Ok so where it echos?

Comment: change the echo $v->getCustomoptionsQty() . ' In Stock '; to echo number_format($v->getCustomoptionsQty(),2). ' In Stock' ;

Answer (score 0):

You can edit **$v->getCustomoptionsQty()** to **number_format($v->getCustomoptionsQty() , 0)**